# UFW default rules... where are they?

Tags: ssh, debian, firewall, iptables, ufw

In the tutorial on UFW here

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW

it says that UFW uses the default rules if enabled and not configured. I checked the folder:

```
/etc/ufw/
```

and the files I found there are

> after.rules
>   after6.rules
>   before.rules
>   before6.rules
>   sysctl.conf
>   ufw.conf

So where are the "default rules"? There are 4 different rules files, and I don't know which on is the one it's gonna choose if I enable it.

I'm afraid if I enable it, it would just block port 22 and I'll lose SSH connection to my server, which is not easy to recover from.

How can I safely start the firewall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may enable UFW, and then issue these commands:

```
   sudo iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
   sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport ssh -j ACCEPT
```

This will surely allow *ssh*. If you like the setup, yu can write these two lines inside the file */etc/rc.local*, and they will be applied at boot (no need of *sudo*, in this case).

**EDIT**

There are basically three files of importance, in /etc/ufw: sysctl.conf, after.rules, before.rules. The remaining files concern rules for IPv6 (after6|before6.rules), the definitions of the port used by a handful of applications (in the subdirectory *./applications.d*), and the file to start *ufw*, *ufw.conf*.

*sysctl.conf* completely replaces /etc/sysctl.conf, it is thus just a duplicate. It contains information for the kernel that is intended as a set of security measures.

The rules are separated in before and after (the lines entered from the command line), because the order matters: when reading a series of rules, the firewall will apply the first rule that is relevant, whether that be ACCEPT, DROP, or whatever; the remaining rules are then *not even read*. It follows that very specific rules precede general rules.

The before rules are simple: they allow loopback and ICMP (=pings), drop *INVALID* packets, allow passage of packets if the conversation has already begun (the equivalent of my rule 1 above), allow DHCP, and local traffic, which is bsolutely essential for the operation of the LAN, *i.e.* especially network discovery, multicast and broadcast.

The after rules only prevent logging of ports which produce too much material.

A single rule can be read as follows:

```
   -A ufw-before-input -p udp --sport 67 --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
```

This adds (-A) to the table *before-input* the rule that ACCEPTs packets of protocol UDP which originated (sport= source port) from port 67 and which are destined for port 68 (dport= destination port). This table is read on INPUT, so that it is ignored whenever the kernel is dealing with an OUTPUT or a FORWARD packet (both types of packets are going out, but OUTPUT packets originated on **this** machine, while FORWARD packets originated elsewhere and are moving on to their final destination).

Comment: Thank you for the response. But can you please explain a little bit more? What are the default rules of UFW? I want to learn to control my firewall and not just copy/paste some commands, if you know what I mean. Thank you.