# Port-forward from and to WAN?

Tags: networking, firewall, port-forwarding, ubuntu-server

Is it possible to port-forward packets FROM the internet to another address ON the internet?

All of the port-forwarding tutorials I've found focus on NAT port-forwarding but I just want to redirect a connection to another public address and I cannot seem to adapt the firewall settings for this purpose. Is it even possible?

I am using `iptables`/`ufw` and I have tried the following (in /etc/ufw/before.rules):

```
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -d $VPS_PUBLIC_IP -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination $PUBLIC_WEB_SERVER_IP:80
```

(I also tried adding `*nat` on the line before that but then I also get a `Bad argument '*nat'` error.)

But I get a "RULE_APPEND failed (Invalid argument): rule in chain PREROUTING" error when I start ufw.

My end goal is to be able to go to (for example) https://1.2.3.4 in the browser and see the (publicly hosted) website at https://9.8.7.6 without a VPN.

**Update:** I am trying to connect from my PC to the VPS and be forwarded to the public web server. My VPS should be doing nothing except forwarding the connection.

Comment: One note, you will almost certainly have issues with HTTPS. it is designed to help people detect when a man-in-the-middle attack like this one is occurring.

Comment: Consider running a reverse proxy instead?  That way you'll still have useful logs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's possible, although you will additionally need an SNAT or MASQUERADE rule for the same packets, so the final destination host will see connections as coming from you and not from the original client. (It is exactly the same situation as port-forwarding from LAN to LAN – "hairpin NAT" becomes necessary to prevent the reply packets from bypassing your gateway, which then would have no opportunity to un-NAT them.)

Note that the "dport" option is written as `--dport`, not `-dport`. (The latter means `-d` with `port` as the destination IP address.)

Comment: Thanks for the tips! The -dport was a typo I made only when posting here and I still get an invalid argument error with the correct spelling. But I am gonna try some more things (also updated the question), thanks again!

Answer (score 7):

If you want a User to be able to access a Website by connecting to a VPS, as in the following diagram, where each network interface is on the WAN (Internet):

```
        e.g. 1.2.3.4
         ┌───────┐
         │  VPS  │
         └───────┘
             ▲        WAN (Internet)
     ┌───────┴───────┐
     ▼               ▼
┌────────┐      ┌─────────┐
│  User  │      │ Website │
└────────┘      └─────────┘
                      e.g. 9.8.7.6 ← example.com
```

Then either of the following two solutions will do that.

## Overview

First, a quick overview of the netfilter design, based
on Rusty Russel's [NAT HOWTO](https://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/NAT-HOWTO-5.html) and
[Packet Filtering HOWTO](https://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/packet-filtering-HOWTO-6.html). You can skip this
section or read it later, and it might make more sense
that way since I wrote this overview last.

```
              (D-NAT)           (S-NAT)
Incoming ╭──────────╮           ╭───────────╮ Outgoing
      ──▶│PREROUTING│           │POSTROUTING│──▶
         ╰──────────╯           ╰───────────╯
                │                  ▲
                ▼     ╭───────╮    │
           Routing ──▶│FORWARD│────┤
           Decision   ╰───────╯    │
                │                  │
                ▼                  │
             ╭─────╮    Local    ╭──────╮
             │INPUT│─▶ Process ─▶│OUTPUT│
             ╰─────╯             ╰──────╯
```

There are these five "hooks" into which you can add rules:

| PREROUTING | INPUT | FORWARD | OUTPUT | POSTROUTING |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

Each hook provides certain features/extensions, such as
D-NAT and S-NAT, which rules can make use of. (Edit:
the different feature sets actually vary by table, such
as "filter" (encompassing INPUT, FORWARD, OUTPUT) and
"nat" (encompassing PREROUTING, INPUT, OUTPUT,
POSTROUTING). I don't have a good understanding of the
tables right now.)

Every incoming packet goes through PREROUTING and every
outgoing packet goes through POSTROUTING. After
PREROUTING (at the "Routing Decision") packets that are
addressed to the local machine go through INPUT, while
other packets go through FORWARD. New packets created
by a process first go through OUTPUT and then through
POSTROUTING, alongside packets that have passed through
FORWARD. (Note: forwarding may be disabled by default.)

Each rule is part of an ordered chain of rules and
rules are evaluated top to bottom (the chains can be
seen by running `iptables -L -t filter` and
`iptables -L -t nat`). Each rule can attempt to match
certain characteristics of a packet and, if it matches,
optionally modify the packet, and decide to either
ACCEPT it (letting it continue onward), DROP it, or jump to another
chain. If no rule matches, the default policy decides
whether to ACCEPT or DROP the packet.

---

Forwarding packets onto the originating network seems
like a rare or unusual thing to do, but it is possible
(see [Destination NAT Onto the Same Network](https://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/NAT-HOWTO-10.html)
and is associated with the MASQUERADE option. (It seems
that ordinarily you want to prevent direct access to a
machine, so you'd put it in a private network, as in the
case of reverse proxies).

The gist is that you need to: (1) enable forwarding,
(2) change the destination address of incoming packets,
and (3) change the source address on the packet so that
the destination does not reply directly to the User (which
would get blocked by a normally configured firewall).
Packets going the other direction (Website to VPS) are
automatically forwarded back to the User.

You may want to tighten the packet matching for the rules
below, if possible, for maximum security. (If, like me,
you're doing this mostly as a learning exercise, it
probably doesn't matter, but it's good to keep this in
mind when playing with *fire*walls.)

## Temporary solution

Run the following commands (adapted from Rusty Russel's
2002 [NAT HOWTO](https://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/NAT-HOWTO.txt) sections [4.1](https://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/NAT-HOWTO-4.html#ss4.1)
and [10](https://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/NAT-HOWTO-10.html)) to add two new NAT rules, one in
the PREROUTING phase, and the other in the POSTROUTING
phase. Substitute the relevant IP addresses if you don't
have them defined as variables.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d $VPS_PUBLIC_IP -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to $PUBLIC_WEB_SERVER_IP
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d $PUBLIC_WEB_SERVER_IP -p tcp --dport 443 -j MASQUERADE
```

For this to work, forwarding must be enabled:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

(see [How Packets Traverse The Filters](https://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/packet-filtering-HOWTO-6.html))

Breakdown of the `iptables` arguments used here (see `man iptables` for details):

- `-t nat` says to use the NAT packet matching table:

  > This table is consulted when a packet
  > that creates a new connection is encountered.
  > It consists of four built-ins: PREROUTING
  > (for altering packets as soon as they come in),
  > INPUT (for altering packets destined for local
  > sockets), OUTPUT (for altering locally-generated
  > packets before routing), and POSTROUTING (for
  > altering packets as they are about to go out).
- `-A PREROUTING` appends the rule to the PREROUTING chain.
- `-A POSTROUTING` appends the rule to the POSTROUTING chain.
- `-d $VPS_PUBLIC_IP` applies the rule when the packet's
  destination is the VPS, i.e. the User has typed `1.2.3.4`
  into their browser.
- `-d $PUBLIC_WEB_SERVER_IP` applies the rule when the
  packet's destination is the web server's public IP. This
  is true after the User's packet has arrived at the VPS
  and passed through the PREROUTING chain (which changed
  the destination address) and the FORWARD chain (which
  didn't change anything).
- `-p tcp` matches packets of the world famous TCP protocol.
- `--dport 443` matches packets headed for port 443 (HTTPS).
- `-j DNAT` stands for "jump to DNAT (Destination-NAT).
  I can't explain it, but `man iptables` says:

  > This specifies the target of the rule; i.e., what
  > to do if the packet matches it. The target can be
  > a user-defined chain (other than the one this rule
  > is in), one of the special builtin targets which
  > decide the fate of the packet immediately, or an
  > extension (see EXTENSIONS below).

  and from `man iptables-extensions`

  > **DNAT** A virtual state, matching if the original
  > destination differs from the reply source.
- `--to $PUBLIC_WEB_SERVER_IP` changes the packet
  *destination* IP (because of *D*NAT) to the web server's IP.
- `-j MASQUERADE` changes the source IP to the VPS's IP,
  equivalent to `-j SNAT --to $VPS_PUBLIC_IP`. This makes
  the web server respond to the VPS, which then unmangles
  the packet and forwards it to the User. Without this,
  the server would respond directly to the User, whose
  firewall would most likely deny it because it is a new
  connection the firewall doesn't recognize.
  For details, see
  [Netfilter's Connection Tracking System](https://people.netfilter.org/pablo/docs/login.pdf)
  and [Saying How To Mangle The Packets](https://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/NAT-HOWTO-6.html).

You will get SSL certificate warnings if the VPS IP is
not listed in the certificate as a SAN (Subject
Alternative Name).

## Permanent solution

To make it permanent with `ufw` (Uncomplicated FireWall),
add the following to /etc/ufw/before.rules (substituting
the actual IP addresses for the VPS and web server).

Note: By default, ufw sets the FORWARD policy to "deny"
(also shown as "DROP" in `iptables -L -t filter`). That
is why the `-A FORWARD ... -j ACCEPT` rule is needed.
If your default policy is ACCEPT (as in `ufw default allow routed`) then it isn't needed.

```
*nat
-A PREROUTING -d $VPS_PUBLIC_IP -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to $PUBLIC_WEB_SERVER_IP
-A POSTROUTING -d $PUBLIC_WEB_SERVER_IP -p tcp --dport 443 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT

*filter
-A FORWARD -d $PUBLIC_WEB_SERVER_IP -p tcp --dport 443  -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

Be sure to put this at the end of the file, after the existing `COMMIT` line. **Also, ensure that you [don't lock yourself out of SSH by reading this answer in full.](https://superuser.com/a/704263)**

Then open /etc/ufw/sysctl.conf and uncomment the lines
where it says to "Uncomment this to allow this host to
route packets between interfaces", so the result should
be:

```
net/ipv4/ip_forward=1
net/ipv6/conf/default/forwarding=1
net/ipv6/conf/all/forwarding=1
```

Then enable ufw:

```
ufw enable
```

If you're connected via SSH it will ask to confirm in
case enabling ufw would block port 22 and lock you out.
That shouldn't happen so just type "y" and press enter.
If you're worried, make a backup/snapshot via your VPS
control panel first.

Test to see if it works. If you run `iptables -L -t filter` you should see a line like this:

```
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            example.com        tcp dpt:443
```

near the top, under the section heading "Chain FORWARD
(policy DROP)". And if you run `iptables -L -t nat`
you should see your rules under the section headings
"Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)" and "Chain POSTROUTING
(policy ACCEPT)".

For details, see [UFW](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW), `man ufw` and `man ufw-framework`.

### Making changes

If you need to make changes, you should probably run
`iptables -F -t nat` to flush out rules in the PREROUTING
and POSTROUTING chains first, or you may get duplicate
rules. If you need to flush rules in the FORWARD chain,
**don't** run `iptables -F -t filter` because [your SSH
session will break](https://askubuntu.com/a/1293947) (if the
default policy for the INPUT chain is deny/DROP) and I
haven't figured out a way to prevent that (even if you
change the default policy, it breaks when you change it
back to deny). Just `reboot` if you don't mind that, or
delete the specific rules: first list them with
`iptables -L --line-numbers -t filter` and then delete
with `iptables -D FORWARD 7` (to delete the 7th rule for
example).

Then restart ufw: `systemctl restart ufw`

Comment: Did you type that ascii art diagram manually, or did you use some tools to help you? If so, which tool?

Comment: I used Monodraw. There is also a free web app called [asciiflow](https://asciiflow.com/).

Answer (score 2):

The "invalid argument" error is probably, as mentioned in another answer, because you need to write `--dport` instead of `dport`.

After you fix this, the rule will be probably accepted, but will probably not do exactly what you want. I am assuming here that you are adding the rule at the same machine that will run the browser, and it is not a separate firewall machine sitting in between. In that case, the packets will not pass the PREROUTING chain, which is only used for packets being routed through this machine. For locally generated packets to be able to get NATed, you need to add the DNAT rule in the OUTPUT chain instead (of the nat table). The complete command would be then:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -i eth0 -d $VPS_PUBLIC_IP -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination $PUBLIC_WEB_SERVER_IP:80
```

Notice, that you don't really need to also have an inverse SNAT rule, because for connections that are initiated from your side (e.g. in the browser), connection tracking will know to do the inverse translation for the return packets that belong to the same connection.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I made the `-dport` mistake only here, so I am getting that error because of something else. Updated the question, but I'm gonna try some more things. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for ufw but when using iptables directly, nat rules must be in the nat table, that means you need "-t nat" in your command line after the "-A prerouting".